# Freeze water bottles during colder nights, and place them in front of a fan during warmer days?

Tags: thermodynamics

1. Is [this advice](https://www.wikihow.com/Make-an-Easy-Homemade-Air-Conditioner-from-a-Fan-and-Water-Bottles) correct? Are they alluding to Freezing Point Depression? Adding salt to tap water lowers the [Crystalloid](https://www.easybiologyclass.com/difference-between-colloids-and-crystalloids-a-comparison-table/)'s freezing point.

> **Pour 3 tbsp (51 g) of salt into each of your 3 plastic water bottles.** Use disposable plastic bottles for the easiest set-up and clean up. Pour 3 tablespoons (51 g) of table salt per bottle. Put the caps back on and shake the bottles to thoroughly mix the salt.

2. I live in a studio flat. I know of the [Law of Thermodynamics](https://old.reddit.com/r/askscience/comments/3cuekw/is_a_diy_air_conditioner_a_thermodynamically_good/cszsr8j/), also [here](https://old.reddit.com/r/askscience/comments/utuw2/would_a_homemade_air_cooler_that_uses_cooper/c4yhbug/)  – but my plan is different. Where I live, night time is way cooler than day time. I'll freeze the bottles over night, because even if my freezer heats up more than usual, my night room temperature will still be cool enough. During day time when it's hot, I'll place the frozen bottles  in front of my fan to air condition my studio flat. Does this work? [I read Quora](https://www.quora.com/Does-putting-a-frozen-water-bootle-in-front-on-a-fan-make-it-move-colder-air-around-the-room).

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few things to consider.

1. The freezer won't be 100% efficient.  It'll probably generate more heat than you expect to freeze the bottles and this will add to the average temperature in your flat.  Operating the fan also generates heat.
2. The freezer might make more noise at night than otherwise.
3. Air conditioners also remove moisture from the air, as well as cooling.  The bottle/fan method wouldn't do this.

It's true that the method would generate a cool breeze, but the overall effect would be a slight increase of the average temperature.

So instead try shutting the curtains on bright days to stop the sun heating your flat,  also open windows at night and shut them in the morning on hot days to keep the night time cool air inside.